# Release Tracking - An error doesnt associate to a recent release

Tags: laravel, sentry

I have setup release tracking on Sentry to keep track of all my releases to production/staging environments however when I submit a purposefully code breaking change and I go trip that error -- It will associate that I have a new error in the 'project' but when I view the 'Releases' tab it will display 0 issues associated to that commit that the known code breaking change originated from.

I am using Laravel 8, Sentry 2.2, and Bitbucket Pipelines to submit my releases.

Is there something that I am missing?

Laravel `Sentry` Config file

```
return [

    'dsn' => env('SENTRY_LARAVEL_DSN', env('SENTRY_DSN')),

    // capture release as git sha
    'release' => trim(exec('git --git-dir ' . base_path('.git') . ' log --pretty="%h" -n1 HEAD')),

    'breadcrumbs' => [
        // Capture Laravel logs in breadcrumbs
        'logs' => true,

        // Capture SQL queries in breadcrumbs
        'sql_queries' => true,

        // Capture bindings on SQL queries logged in breadcrumbs
        'sql_bindings' => true,

        // Capture queue job information in breadcrumbs
        'queue_info' => true,
    ],

];
```

Bitbucket Yaml file

```
...
      - step:
          name: Staging - Sentry Commit Tracking
          script:
            - pipe: sentryio/sentry-new-release:0.3.0
              variables:
                SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN: $SENTRY_STAGING_AUTH_TOKEN
                SENTRY_ORG: $SENTRY_STAGING_ORG
                SENTRY_PROJECT: $SENTRY_STAGING_PROJECT
...
```

P.S. If youre in the Sentry Discord Server please see #php
https://discordapp.com/channels/621778831602221064/621964286952210432/782383789762281482
Just make sure you read down to about 5pm PST 11/29/2020

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to latest Sentry and was able to get it to work properly.